# pxssh.pxssh() is producing error in python

Tags: python-2.7

I got the following errors when I run pxssh.pxssh() in python. Please let me know what I am missing here.

---

```
    Exception AttributeError: "'pxssh' object has no attribute 'closed'" in <bound method pxssh.__del__ of <pexpect.pxssh.pxssh object at 0x10d98e910>> ignored
.........
    File "/Users/any_user/system/somelibrary_lib.py", line 377, in login
    ssh = pxssh.pxssh(maxread=read_buffer, ignore_sighup=False)
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ignore_sighup'
```

.........

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. the solution was like this :

```
s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=time_out, maxread=2000000)
s.SSH_OPTS += " -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
s.SSH_OPTS += " -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
```

You should add this two options

Comment: It works like a charm, thanks so much you saved my day sir!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Solution I found was to use `SSH_OPTS` property of `pxssh` object instead of `options` ctor (`__init__`) argument.
So my code looks like this:

```
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.SSH_OPTS += " -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
s.force_password = True
s.login(ip, user, passwd)
```

It doesn't throw `AttributeError` exception on module initialization and `TypeError` too.
But it still doesn't work for me. If the remote server has [`MOTD`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motd_%28Unix%29) or some shell initialization on startup, it would break the logic of `pxssh`. I made the following trick:

```
s.login(ip, user, passwd, original_prompt = "Last login:")
```

Shell writes on each successful login line like `Last login: %date% from %ip%`. I used it to verify successful logon. Now, using `s` you can execute remote commands.
Original (default) value for `original_prompt` is `r"[#$]"`. May be you need somehow to combine them for correct `pxssh` work. May be you need to add `>` to `original_prompt` if you are connecting to `SQL` shell or `Cisco` devices.